# “Un/des tas de choses” - what's the difference?

Tags: sens, pluriel

"J'ai **une tonne de** trucs à faire."

"J'ai **des tonnes de** trucs à faire."

The same question about "un tas de choses" and "des tas de choses". Does the ones with "des" imply a larger quantity?

Answer (score 6):

No, there is no difference in meaning. All of these hyperboles just imply an unspecified large quantity, just like this alternative:

> J'ai un million de trucs à faire.

Here is an attempt to show a gradation in the amount of things to do:

> - *J'ai deux trois trucs à faire / quelques trucs à faire.*  (a couple, a few)
> - *J'ai pas mal de trucs à faire.* (some, quite a few)
> - *J'ai un paquet/un tas/des tas/beaucoup de trucs à faire.* (a lot, a bunch, quite a few)
> - *J'ai une tonne/des tonnes/un million/un milliard/énormément de trucs à faire.* (a huge number, an awful lot, an enormous amount, tons)

Answer (score 2):

The difference would be:

- J’ai une tonne de trucs à faire = I have a ton of things to do
- J’ai des tonnes de trucs à faire = I have tons of things to do